# Graphing the inverse function on a specific interval

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this

[image]

So, I created this code

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-base,tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
                \begin{axis}[scale=1.3, x=1cm, y=1cm, axis lines=middle, xmin=-3.5, xmax=7, ymin=-3, ymax=6, xtick={-3,...,6}, ytick={-2,...,5},]
                    \draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=0:6.5] plot(\x,{2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x });
                    \draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=-2:6] plot({2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x ,\x});
                    \draw[line width=1pt, color=black, smooth, samples=100, domain=-1.2:6] plot(\x,{\x});
                    \draw[color=red , thick,<->] (0.3,-2)--(1.7,-2);
                    \draw[line width=0.1pt, color=black, dashed](1,0)|-(0,-2);
                    \draw[line width=0.1pt, color=black, dashed](4.4816,0)|-(0,4.4816);
                    \node[black, rotate=45] at (3,3.4) {$(\Delta):y = x$}; % y = x
                    \node[black] at (4.4816,0) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
                    \node[left,yshift=-1mm] at (0,4.6) {{\small $e^{\frac{3}{2}}$}};
                    \node[left,yshift=-2.5mm] at (4.8,0) {{\small $e^{\frac{3}{2}}$}};
                    \node[left,yshift=-2mm] at (2.9,-0.1) {{\small $e$}};
                    \node[black] at (0,4.4816) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
                    \node[black] at (2.7182,0) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
                    \draw[color=red , thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,-0.9);
                    \draw[color=red , thick, ->] (-2,1)--(-2,1.7);
                    \begin{scriptsize}
                        \draw[color=blue] (2.8,1.4) node {$(C_f)$};
                    \end{scriptsize}
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't give me the same results + I get some errors and I don't know how to fix them

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable! It throws error "missing number" ...  Why you not use `\pgfplots` for determine axis, ticks, etc. ?

Comment: @Zarko, please see below. It arises from the attempt to calculate the inverse ... which doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 3):

Analysis, kind of debugging ... :

- commenting all out
- stepwise commenting in
- doing some code formatting & comments
- revealing 4 unused packages

Your problem is, that you can't calculate an inverse this way by simply "swapping" variables:

- `\draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=-2:6] plot({2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x ,\x});`

Suggestion:

- drop inline calculation via `\draw`
- store as (table) data instead
- read said data, with and without swapped columns
- plot that
- use `pgfplot` more consistently

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
                            %\usepackage{tikz,tkz-base,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tikz}
                            %\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,%>=triangle 45,
                    x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[scale=1.3, x=1cm, y=1cm, axis lines=middle, 
                xmin=-3.5, xmax=7, ymin=-3, ymax=6, 
                xtick={-3,...,6}, ytick={-2,...,5},]
                
        % ~~~ function C_f ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=0:6.5] plot(\x,{2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x });
        
        % ~~~ "inverse" ~~~ No ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%       \draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=-2:6] plot({2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x ,\x});

        % ~~~ diagonal ~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[line width=1pt, color=black, smooth, samples=100, domain=-1.2:6] plot(\x,{\x});
            
        % ~~~ labels, marks etc. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[color=red , thick,<->] (0.3,-2)--(1.7,-2);
        \draw[line width=0.1pt, color=black, dashed](1,0)|-(0,-2);
        \draw[line width=0.1pt, color=black, dashed](4.4816,0)|-(0,4.4816);
        
        \node[black, rotate=45] at (3,3.4) {$(\Delta):y = x$}; % y = x
        \node[black] at (4.4816,0) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
        \node[left,yshift=-1mm] at (0,4.6) {{\small $e^{\frac{3}{2}}$}};
        \node[left,yshift=-2.5mm] at (4.8,0) {{\small $e^{\frac{3}{2}}$}};
        \node[left,yshift=-2mm] at (2.9,-0.1) {{\small $e$}};
        \node[black] at (0,4.4816) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
        \node[black] at (2.7182,0) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
        
        \draw[color=red , thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,-0.9);
        \draw[color=red , thick, ->] (-2,1)--(-2,1.7);
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \draw[color=blue] (2.8,1.4) node {$(C_f)$};
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice work! Is it ti early that I would  fit to search a cause of error :-).  +1 for your effort, but your code still not exploit `pgfplots` possibilities :-( ....

Comment: Thank you. Right, that‘s why I made the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch how to do it in `pgfplots`, showing most, not all, required features. Using `tikz` within the `coordinate system` of the plot is out of my scope at the moment ;-) Please refine as needed.

Key ideas:

- calculate the 3 required funtions as data tables (manually in this case)
- turn on the major grid
- put some labels and markers as needed

Hint:

- `\addplot ... ;` seems to define a path
- that's why you can put any numer of nodes after it
- which is a way to put text, symbols etc.

Save function data as `fnc.dat`:

```
x   y
0   0
0.1 -0.6605170
0.5 -1.6931472
1.0 -2.
1.5 -1.7836047
2.0 -1.2274113
2.5 -0.4185463
3.0 0.5916737
3.5 1.7693408 
4.0 3.0903549
4.5 4.5366966
5.0 6.0943791
5.5 7.7522290
```

Exchange data only and save as `inv.dat`:

```
x               y
0               0   
-0.6605170      0.1 
-1.6931472      0.5 
-2.             1.0 
-1.7836047      1.5 
-1.2274113      2.0 
-0.4185463      2.5 
0.5916737       3.0 
1.7693408       3.5 
3.0903549       4.0 
4.5366966       4.5 
6.0943791       5.0 
7.7522290       5.5
```

Because it's so simple let's save `lin.dat` too, or calculate it within pgfplots:

```
x   y
-3 -3
7  7
```

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[
    title={$C_f(x)$ and its inverse},
    xlabel={$x$}, 
    ylabel={$y$}, 
    grid=major,
 ]
    % ~~~ function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[blue ] table {fnc.dat} 
        %~~~  marking zero ~~~~
        node[pos=.38,circle,draw] {}
        % ~~~ putting text ~~~~~~
        node[pos=.38,xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm] {$(e,0)$}
        % ~~~ name of the curve ~~~~~~~
        [xshift=15pt]%  moving the label to right of curve
        node[pos=.5] {$(C_f)$};
        
    % ~~~ inverse ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[black] table {inv.dat}
        [yshift=4mm,xshift=-2mm]
        node[pos=.3] {inverse};
        
    % ~~~ linear ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[green!80!black!100] table {lin.dat}% could be calculated 
        %~~~  marking intersection ~~~~
        node[pos=.74,circle,draw] {}
        % ~~~ putting text ~~~~~~
        node[pos=.74,xshift=8mm,yshift=-3mm] {$(e^{1.5},e^{1.5})$}
        % ~~~ name of the curve ~~~~~~~~~~      
        [yshift=3mm]
        node[pos=.45,sloped] {$(\Delta):y = x$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

### inverse function: `tzfn'`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\tzhelplines[thick](-4,-3)(8,8)
\tzaxes(-4,-3)(8,8){$x$}{$y$}
\tzshoworigin
\tzticks{-3,-2,-1,1,2,...,7}{-2,-1,1,2,...,7}
\def\Gx{2*\x*ln(\x)-2*\x}
\def\ray{\x}
\tzfn\ray[-2:7]{$y=x$}[r]
\tzfn[blue]\Gx[.001:5]{$g$}[a]
\tzfn'[red]\Gx[1:5]{$g^{-1}$}[r] % inverse function
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### full code

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\tzhelplines(-4,-3)(8,8)
\tzaxes(-4,-3)(8,8){$x$}{$y$}
\tzshoworigin
\tzticks{-3,-2,-1,1,2,...,7}{-2,-1,1,2,...,7}
% graphs
\def\Gx{2*\x*ln(\x)-2*\x}
\def\ray{\x}
\tzfn\ray[-2:7]{$y=x$}[r]
\tzfn[blue]"Gx"\Gx[.001:5]{$g$}[a]
\tzfn'[red]"iGx"\Gx[1:5]{$g^{-1}$}[r] % inverse function
% slopes and intersections
\tzXpoint*{Gx}{iGx}(X)
\tzslopeat[<->,red]{Gx}{1}{1cm}
\tzline+[->,red,thick](-2,1)(0,.5) % ad hoc
\tzproj*(1,-2)
\tzXpoint*[blue]{Gx}{axes}(ex){$e$}[b]  % y-intercept
\tzXpoint*[red]{iGx}{axes}(ey){$e$}[l]  % x-intercept
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys

I actually solved it just by changing the domain from `domain=-2:6` to `domain=1:6`

I forgot to swap domain when I swap variables

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
                            %\usepackage{tikz,tkz-base,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tikz}
                            %\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,%>=triangle 45,
                    x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[scale=1.3, x=1cm, y=1cm, axis lines=middle, 
                xmin=-3.5, xmax=7, ymin=-3, ymax=6, 
                xtick={-3,...,6}, ytick={-2,...,5},]
                
        % ~~~ function C_f ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=0:6.5] plot(\x,{2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x });
        
       \draw[line width=1pt, color=blue, smooth, samples=100, domain=1:6] plot({2 *\x * ln \x - 2*\x ,\x});

        % ~~~ diagonal ~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[line width=1pt, color=black, smooth, samples=100, domain=-1.2:6] plot(\x,{\x});
            
        % ~~~ labels, marks etc. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[color=red , thick,<->] (0.3,-2)--(1.7,-2);
        \draw[line width=0.1pt, color=black, dashed](1,0)|-(0,-2);
        \draw[line width=0.1pt, color=black, dashed](4.4816,0)|-(0,4.4816);
        
        \node[black, rotate=45] at (3,3.4) {$(\Delta):y = x$}; % y = x
        \node[black] at (4.4816,0) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
        \node[left,yshift=-1mm] at (0,4.6) {{\small $e^{\frac{3}{2}}$}};
        \node[left,yshift=-2.5mm] at (4.8,0) {{\small $e^{\frac{3}{2}}$}};
        \node[left,yshift=-2mm] at (2.9,-0.1) {{\small $e$}};
        \node[black] at (0,4.4816) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
        \node[black] at (2.7182,0) {{\tiny \ding{53}}};
        
        \draw[color=red , thick, ->] (0,0)--(0,-0.9);
        \draw[color=red , thick, ->] (-2,1)--(-2,1.7);
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \draw[color=blue] (2.8,1.4) node {$(C_f)$};
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]